# mmauth , mmremotecluster, mmremotefs configured correctly but mmmount is not working

Tags: centos, mount, remote

I'm trying to get some multi cluster thing working between two of our GPFS
clusters.

In the "client" cluster, when trying to mount the "remote" cluster, I get:

```
[root@gpfs2 ~]# mmmount all
Tue Dec 10 18:54:46 IST 2019: mmmount: Mounting file systems ...
mount: mount gpfs2 on /gpfs/storage failed: Connection timed out

[root@gpfs2 ~]# mmmount gpfs2
Tue Dec 10 18:18:55 IST 2019: mmmount: Mounting file systems ...
mount: mount gpfs2 on /gpfs/storage failed: Connection timed out
mmmount: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.

[root@gpfs2 ~]# mmmount gpfs1
mmmount: File system gpfs1 is not known to the GPFS cluster.
mmmount: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.
```

`mmauth`, `mmremotecluster`, `mmremotefs` configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When everything is configured correctly, it usually works. So something is probably not quite correct.. You should check /var/adm/ras/mmfs.log.latest on your client cluster, for more details about the errors.

My first guess would be that you have a problem with IP address resolution on the client cluster. Maybe it can't look up the addresses for your storage cluster -- or maybe it doesn't have network connectivity to the daemon network of the storage cluster ?